# Execute MathJax for custom tags without delimiters

Tags: mathjax

I want to use mathjax on our page and i have a custom tag with the formulas `<formula>`.

However it works only when i use delimiters inside my custom tag, is it possible to get rich of the delimiter?

When i set `inlineMath: [['', '']]` the whole thing hangs up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
 <script>
   MathJax = {
  tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$']]},
  startup: {
    elements: ['formula'],
    ready: function () {
   MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
   }
 </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>hello world</p>
 <p>this is a <formula>x^2 + y^2 = z^2</formula> formula x^2 + y^2 = z^2</p>
 <p>this is a <formula>$x^2 + y^2 = z^2$</formula> formula x^2 + y^2 = z^2</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to the [example](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/v2.html#math-script-example) given in the documentation that shows how to process the old v2-style `<script>` tags that used to be used to hold the math.

Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script> 
MathJax = {
  options: {
    renderActions: {
      find: [10, function (doc) {
        for (const node of document.querySelectorAll('formula')) {
          const math = new doc.options.MathItem(node.textContent, doc.inputJax[0], false);
          const text = document.createTextNode('');
          node.parentNode.replaceChild(text, node);
          math.start = {node: text, delim: '', n: 0};
          math.end = {node: text, delim: '', n: 0};
          doc.math.push(math);
        }
      }, '']
    }
  }
};
</script> 
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<p>this is a <formula>x^2 + y^2 = z^2</formula> formula x^2 + y^2 = z^2</p>
```

Note that this replaces the usual math-finding function with this one that looks for `<formula>` tags, so if you want to use the original delimiters as well, change the `find: [10` to `findTags: [9` so that the original will not be replaced and will run after your code runs.

Note also that this does not give you a means of distinguishing display-style math from in-line math (as the TeX delimiters do), so all the math is in in-line style.  You could, of course, modify the code to have two different tags, or allow an attribute on `<formula>` to specify display style.